# Add a delay to the default animation in the layout transitions

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a GridLayout in a LinearLayout, they both have layout transitions:

```
screenContainer.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
screenContainer.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

grid.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

I need to delay the transitions of the `screenContainer` for about 300 millis, I know there's a class called LayoutAnimationController, is it the class I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles into this here's the sulution:

```
LayoutTransition transicion = new LayoutTransition();
transicion.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
transicion.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGING, 300);  
screenContainer.setLayoutTransition(transicion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use handler and give 300 milliseconds post delayed, your problem will be solve !

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // Call here
      }
    }, 300);
```

Comment: What I need is to customize the animation to add it a delay after changes in the layout occur